# Want to block downloading files like .doc, .dat, .mp3, .wav, .avi .rar, .exe using squid Proxy in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: proxy, squid

I want to block downloading files like .doc, .dat, .mp3, .wav, .avi .rar, .exe using squid Proxy in Ubuntu 22.04 but unable to do already tried many option with urlpath_regex parameter. Examples are given below :-

```
acl block_exe url_regex .*\.exe$
http_access deny block_exe
------------------------
Blocking file types in squid
First of all, create an ACL file includes all the file types to block downloading them.
[root@server ~]# vi /etc/squid/bad_files.acl
\.[Ee][Xx][Ee]$                                       #block downloading exe executable files
\.[Mm][Pp]3 $                                         #Block mp3 music files
\.[Zz][Ii][Pp]$                                          #Block ZIP archive files
\.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]$                                  #Block jpeg picture files
\.[Aa][Vv][Ii]$                                          #Block avi video files
\.[Tt][Oo][Rr][Rr][Ee][Nn][Tt]$                 #Block torrent files
#(Add the above required file extensions types and save the file)
```

Then, edit the squid configuration file and add an ACL for above created acl file.

```
acl badfiles urlpath_regex "/etc/squid/bad_files.acl"             (ACL for blocked file types)
http_access deny badfiles lan                                               (Deny the file types to lan)
#(Add the above three lines and save the squid.conf file)
```

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you actually tried, and which error you get.

Comment: Try: acl block urlpath_regex -i \.exe$ \.mp3$ \.wav$ \.zip$ \.rar$ \.mp$ \.mpg$ \.wma$ \.mov$ \.wmv$ \.avi$ \.flv$ \.asf$ \.iso$ \.rm$ \.ra$ \.ogg$ \.bin$ \.cab$ \.tar$ \.bz2$